# Get Friendly Enum Name as IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, enums, iqueryable

We used to store our Enums in a database table that had a `Code` property that corresponded to Enums in the application. The point of this was that we could give the Enums in the database a friendly name which allowed us to access it easily when needed.

Recently we stopped having an Enum table in the database and used the Description attribute on each Enum and used reflection to get the Description as the friendly name. This was great as it meant we had less tables in the database.

Here is the `Description` extension method:

```
public static string Description(this Enum source)
{
    var field = source.GetType().GetField(source.ToString());

    var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])field.GetCustomAttributes(
        typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

    return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].Description : source.ToString();
}
```

Now I've come across the problem when performing a Linq `Select` statement on the DatabaseContext (I need to keep it as an `IQueryable`) that we can't use the extension method on the Enum to get the friendly name as Entity Framework wont recognise methods.

The current code is shown below. The `ItemPriority` is assigned the Enumn description attribute which uses reflection. This code falls over as EF can't recognise the method.

```
return await OrderItems(items).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
                .Select(item => new ItemViewModel
                {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    Description = item.Description,
                    ItemPriority = item.Priority.Description(),
                }).ToListAsync();
```

Is there another way I can apply friendly names to Enums or is having the friendly names in the database the only way to go? If I used the database I could just do the following:

```
return await OrderItems(items).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
                .Select(item => new ItemViewModel
                {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    Description = item.Description,
                    ItemPriority = item.Priority.Name,
                }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: My advice, leave your `enum` as `int` based, store them in the database as `int`, when you display them then use the friendly name (attribute). What you have done (if i understand you correctly) is made it easy to read your DB visually yet hard to do anything else

Comment: Can you show the static class with `Description()` extension method? Or at least the class name and method signature. Just to be able to provide you a concrete workable option.

Comment: Updated now with Description method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you should store the `enum` value in the view model and let the view format it with friendly description (using your extension method) or whatever it likes.

But let say for some reason you need that functionality in LINQ to Entities query. It can be achieved by dynamically building EF compatible value to description translation expression like this:

```
source == value1 ? description1 :
source == value2 ? description2 :
…
source == valueN ? descriptionN :

""
```

In order to do that, first you need to make the `Description` method *generic*. This way the call will include the information about actual enum type which we'll need later (since we are going to process the query expression tree, the method will not actually be called):

```
public static class DescriptionExtensions
{
    public static string Description<TEnum>(this TEnum source) where TEnum : struct, Enum
        => typeof(TEnum).GetField(source.ToString()).Description();

    public static string Description(this FieldInfo source)
        => source.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()?.Description ?? source.Name;
}
```

Note that this is utilizing the C# 7.3 introduced [enum constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-3#enhanced-generic-constraints). For pre C# 7.3 use `where TEnum : struct` and assert `typeof(TEnum).IsEnum` inside the method.

Then we'll use a custom extension method which finds the `Description` method calls inside the query expression tree and replaces it with the aforementioned value to description translation expression, which is based on the `TEnum` type of the call. As usual with expression tree, the processing is done with custom `ExpressionVisitor`.

```
public static class QueryConverter
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Convert<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
    {
        var expression = new ExpressionConverter().Visit(source.Expression);
        if (expression == source.Expression) return source;
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);
    }

    class ExpressionConverter : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        static readonly MethodInfo EnumDescriptionMethod = Expression.Call(
            typeof(DescriptionExtensions), nameof(DescriptionExtensions.Description), new[] { typeof(ExpressionType) },
            Expression.Constant(default(ExpressionType)))
            .Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();

        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Method.IsGenericMethod && node.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition() == EnumDescriptionMethod)
                return TranslateEnumDescription(Visit(node.Arguments[0]));
            return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
        }

        static Expression TranslateEnumDescription(Expression arg)
        {
            var names = Enum.GetNames(arg.Type);
            var values = Enum.GetValues(arg.Type);
            Expression result = Expression.Constant("");
            for (int i = names.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var value = values.GetValue(i);
                var description = arg.Type.GetField(names[i], BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).Description();
                // arg == value ? description : ...
                result = Expression.Condition(
                    Expression.Equal(arg, Expression.Constant(value)),
                    Expression.Constant(description),
                    result);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Now all you need to get EF compatible `IQueryable<T>` from query containing `Description` calls is to call the custom `Convert` method at the end:

```
var query = OrderItems(items)
    .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .Select(item => new ItemViewModel
    {
        Id = item.Id,
        Description = item.Description,
         ItemPriority = item.Priority.Description(),
    })
    .Convert();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This is definitely something I will utilise